# MySQL: How to insert the result of stored procedure into temporary table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to insert the results of a stored procedure into a temporary table, like this:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE NEWBalance (VendorAmount NUMERIC(15,2),   
                                   UserBalanceAmount NUMERIC(15,2));  

INSERT NEWBalance call SP VenAccNo,PeopleId;
```

But that produces an error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'call SP VenAccNo,PeopleId' at line 1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately you still can't do that in MySql.

A possible solution is to modify your SP and make it do INSERT into a temporary table.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE your_sp(...)
BEGIN
    -- do your processing
    ...
    -- insert results into a temporary table
    INSERT INTO NEWBalance ...
    SELECT ...;
END
```

Then your flow is like this

```
CREATE temporary TABLE NEWBalance 
(
 VendorAmount NUMERIC(15,2),
 UserBalanceAmount NUMERIC(15,2)
);

CALL your_sp (...);

-- do your processing on data in a temporary table
...

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE NEWBalance;
```